# How do I trigger a gulp task from pipe?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, incremental-build

In the gulpfile I would like to write something like

```
watch = require 'gulp-watch'
gulp.task 'mytask', ->
  gulp.src '*.txt'
  .pipe watch('*.txt')
  .pipe gulp.trigger('echo')
  .pipe gulp.dest('tmp')
```

so the task 'echo' should be started each time a text file is changed.
Note that I would like the task 'echo' to be started just once, even if two or more files were modified.

I came across `gulp.trigger` [by searching the web](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/32) , but it seems to be a deprecated feature. In any, case, the code above yields `TypeError: Object #<Gulp> has no method 'trigger'`

So is there any option to trigger a task this way?

P.S. In principle, one could workaround like

```
watch '*.txt', ->
  runSequence(...)
```

but this way is not incremental (to my knowledge). And I want to put into tmp only the modified files.

**UPD.** It seems I have found a better workaround:

```
transform = require('vinyl-transform')
map_stream = require('map-stream')
run_sequence = require('run-sequence')

gulp.task 'mytask', ->
  mytrigger = transform (filename) ->
    run_sequence('echo')
    map_stream (chunk, next) -> next(null, chunk)
  gulp.src '*.txt'
  .pipe watch('*.txt')
  .pipe mytrigger
  .pipe gulp.dest('tmp')
```

So I wrap the task 'echo' into a stream.
But maybe there is a more elegant way?